# Trying to view Table in H2 database While using the Grails as a Framework

Tags: database, grails, groovy, h2

recently I am dealing with grails. I am creating a very simple CRUD application without Scaffolding. I have created a Domain class. As I know This domain Class will automatically create a Table in the default H2 database. I am trying to view that table. How can I view The Table which was created in the H2 database? I want To view like the following image.

[image]

Comment: MyDomain.all give you all the records in that table.  If you want to "look at" the table, AFAIR a db-console starts up with grails.  You might have to be more specific, what you mean by "how can i view the table".

Comment: I edited My question. I hope It clears my question.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get it.  You already view it in db-console?  You want to have that same view just with grails?  Why not use the scaffolding stuff?  Or use `Doctur.all` and then some view that renders it as a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your grails app should give you the endpoint '/dbconsole' in dev mode. just give it a try!